# vb.net wraptext of a radiobutton

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, word-wrap

In vb.net 2019, not C#.
I have five radio buttons in a flowlayoutpanel, with `flowdirection = topdown`, and `autoscroll=false`.
The radio buttons have `autosize=true` and `max size = (500,100)`
I need to wraptext of these radiobuttons, they take their text from a textfile , so sometimes it's just one line that fits, other times ,it's two or three lines, I want to wrap these lines because the radio buttons show them in one line only.

Comment: The internal renderer uses `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak` when `AutoSize = false`. In this case, the text is drawn to fit the blackbox (the drawing box, font overhanging and padding considered - and the glyph size, in this case). But of course the Control is not auto sized. You could measure the text yourself, using the current size as reference and adjusting to fit the maximum size you've set. Probably better if you provide a [custom LayoutEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine) to perform the core calculation.

Comment: yea, I used a textrenderer to get the width of the text and divide it over the radio width. thanks